# How to convert binary string to binary byte array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, binary, binary-data

I have binary string like this: String a = "100100". 
I need to have binary byte array: byte[] b = {1,0,0,1,0,0} for output.

This is my code:

```
    String a="100100";

    byte[] b = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++) {
        b[i]=a.charAt(i)=='1'? (byte) 1: (byte) 0;
        System.out.println("b["+i+"]: "+b[i]);
    }
```

But this approach is not working when i run it.
Can any one give a correction? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

byte[] is not initialized. So we need to initialize before we use it .

```
byte[] b = new byte[a.length()];

try this
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't assigned a value to your `byte[] b`, hence resulting in a `NullPointerException`, since you later reference it by index.

Try this instead:

```
String a="100100";

byte[] b = new byte[a.length()]; // here
for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++) {
    b[i]=a.charAt(i)=='1'? (byte) 1: (byte) 0;
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(b)); // easier print once finished
```

**Output**

```
[1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
```